# Parse JSON values as javascript object literals

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, object-literal

I have a rest service that creates me some typescript code like this:

```
var parametrosUpdate = {
"compania": "this['variable_COMPANIA']",
"elemento": "this['variable_ELEMENTO']",
"serie": "this['variable_SERIE']"
};
```

However, i have a variable called variable_COMPANIA, and i need to 
parse the json as follows:

```
var variable_COMPANIA = 'value here';

var parametrosUpdate= {
"compania": this['variable_COMPANIA'],
"elemento": this['variable_ELEMENTO'],
"serie": this['variable_SERIE']
};
```

So, basically i need to parse the json to a object literal to use properly as a javascript var.

I have tried already the JSON.parse() function but it doesn't worked to me.

Comment: Why is `parametrosUpdate` created this way? What is `this`?

Comment: @talemyn sure. 

    JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({"compania": "this['variable_COMPANIA']",....}));

Note: Keep in mind that the parametrosUpdate var is not an string, is JSON. But i need to keep the "compania" value as the value of the javascript variable, not the string "this['variable..."

Comment: @adiga It is part of an Angular component, so it is typescript code inside a component's  code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var parametrosUpdate = {
"compania": "this['variable_COMPANIA']",
"elemento": "this['variable_ELEMENTO']",
"serie": "this['variable_SERIE']"
};

var variable_COMPANIA = 'value here';

x = parametrosUpdate['compania']
// outputs: "this['variable_COMPANIA']"

eval(x)
// outputs: 'value here'

// if you want to transform the whole object into a new, parsed version, just do:
Object.assign(...Object.entries(parametrosUpdate).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: eval(v)})))
```

My guts say me that you don't really need (or want) this. Maybe this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Could you give a little more context on what you are trying to do?

Comment: I really don't like the "EVAL" function but i think it is a good answer. +1 for this.

Comment: Ok. Good to know that you are aware of the dangers of `eval`. In this case, I just edited the answer to provide an elegant way to transform the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach:

```
String.ptototype.toLiteral = function () {
    try {
        return eval(this);
    } catch(err) {
        throw new Error('Incorrect javascript');
    }
};

Object.keys(parametrosUpdate).map(x => parametrosUpdate[x] = parametrosUpdate[x].toLiteral());
```

Or just:

```
Object.keys(parametrosUpdate).map(x => parametrosUpdate[x] = eval(parametrosUpdate[x]));
```